# Create multiple nodes with JavaScript and SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Is it possible to create multiple nodes? I have this:

```
var = document.getElementById('svgID');
var ellipse = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'ellipse'); 
test.setAttribute('cx', x);
test.setAttribute('cy', y);
test.setAttribute('rx', w);
test.setAttribute('ry', h);
test.appendChild(ellipse);
```

Well, I can duplicate the code above, rename it and create so multiple nodes, but is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: use a loop perhaps?

Comment: Yes, but this will create the same node. I need to separate the nodes like "classes in object-oriented programming".

Comment: No, it will create multiple nodes.

Comment: But I need to separete the nodes like test1, test2, test3, ect. This way every node has his own parent.

Answer (score 0):

Easier like

```
addEllipse('svgID', {cx:x, cy:y, rx:w, ry:h}, test);


function addEllipse(svgID, info, toDom) {
  var = document.getElementById(svgID);
  var ellipse = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'ellipse'); 
  toDom.setAttribute('cx', info.cx);
  toDom.setAttribute('cy', info.cy);
  toDom.setAttribute('rx', info.rx);
  toDom.setAttribute('ry', info.ry);
  toDom.appendChild(ellipse);
}
```

Comment: I think my question was a bit confusing. If I declared an ID in SVG like this: <svg id = "test"> </ svg> I can not create multiple nodes in JavaScript. What can I do in this situation? Can I create the SVG object directly in JavaScript instead of in the HTML body?

Comment: I must admit I'm not sure what you're looking for. Perhaps you want to copy one SVG and use it as a template for creating others? Vue.js would make this easy but only if you've got your head around it.

Comment: @JCss If you look at this [article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/love-generating-svg-javascript-move-to-server/), it mentions 3 libraries (Raphaël.js, Snap.svg and svg.js) to do that, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.

My problem was that my data structure was object-oriented and it was not possible to add the SVG objects to the classes because the SVG objects are added to the DOM. So I change it so that it work's procedural.